# In Crystal, how would I detect a zombie process?

Tags: crystal-lang

I sometimes create Process instances (ie `Process.new`).  They register as existing and not terminated even though they are in a zombie state after running `.kill` on them.

What is the recommended way of detecting them as zombies within Crystal?

Comment: Kudos for the most interesting question title of the day ;)

Comment: @Extragorey I should have titled it: "How can I detect zombies with my Crystal?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do processes killed in a Signal trap block become zombies instead of terminated regularly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50811354/why-do-processes-killed-in-a-signal-trap-block-become-zombies-instead-of-termina)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [`#wait`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.25.1/Process.html#wait%3AProcess%3A%3AStatus-instance-method) on the process instance after killing it to collect the zombie process and than it should be [`#terminated?`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.25.1/Process.html#terminated%3F-instance-method).