# Why do processes killed in a Signal trap block become zombies instead of terminated regularly?

Tags: crystal-lang

If I created processes with `Process.new`, they can be killed with `.kill`. However, they become zombies in a Signal trap:

```
PROCESSES = {} of Int32 => Process

spawn {
  loop { sleep 1 }
}

spawn {
  x = Process.new("sleep", "100".split)
  x.kill
  sleep 0.4
  puts x.terminated?

  x = Process.new("sleep", "100".split)
  PROCESSES[x.pid] = x
}


Signal::INT.trap {
  Signal::INT.reset
  PROCESSES.each { |pid, x|
    puts "killing: #{pid}"
    x.kill
    sleep 1
    puts "killed #{pid}? #{x.terminated?}"
  }
}
sleep
```

Running this code with `crystal run` and sending a SIGINT to the process, will always have `.terminated?` return true for the process because it is in a zombie (`<defunct>`) state.

Comment: After seeing so may issues with threads in several platforms and languages, I would recommend never kill a thread, the memory gets inconsistent thus the next thing you should do is restart your machine.

Answer (score 3):

Processes become zombies when their parent does not collect their status, that is when it doesn't call any of the `wait` family of functions.

For your example you should keep the `Process` instance around and call `Process#wait` after sending the kill signal. If you want to do this concurrently for many process just surround each call to `wait` with a `spawn`.